# how to make dots inherit the width of the image? (slick)

Tags: html, css

There is a block 225px. Inside you insert a picture large size (850px). And she goes outside.

*It looks like this:*

```css
.content {display: inline-block;}

.column {float:right; width:225px;}

.slider {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.single-slide img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
    <div class="column">
      <div class="slider single-slide">
        <div><img src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2c/d0/19/2cd0197c5eb8c1f84e81734f97e80cd3.jpg' /></div>
        <div>to place the center of the image</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). I want to add dots to control the slider.

When I add the dots they are placed in the middle of the block. It's okay, I understand. **But I want to place them in the center of the picture.** **How to do it?**

UPD: The image goes beyond the block, that's right! And I need to do to the dots were at the center of the image, not the block

Comment: if you want to need image in box then change .single-slide img { width: auto;} to .single-slide img { max-width: 100%;}

Answer (score 0):

I see that your dots are in the center of the window.
To do this, your dots list must be inside a container with the image's width.

I think you should enlarge your slider or limit image's width with a `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: removed dots from the code. How to place `ul` inside the block `.column` so he was at the centre of the image and not the centre of the block?

Comment: Your slides shoud not be larger than the slider. I think you need `max-width: 100%;` on img then add `position: relative` on the slider. So the dots will be centered

Comment: how to make dots inherit the width of the image?

Comment: I'm sorry but you can not because the dots are not children of the image !
Or you need to do a complex JavaScript.
Why don't you enlarge the slider instead ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to need image in box then change

`.single-slide img { width: auto;}`

to

```
.single-slide img { max-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: I not correctly described the problem. The image goes beyond the block, that's right! And I need to do to the dots were at the center of the image, not the block

Comment: how to make dots inherit the width of the image?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** The **inherit** keyword specifies that a property should **inherit** its value from its **parent** element [ [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp) ]. and image can't be a parent element. see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jhvq09fq/1/).

**Here is a solution on based on inherit and position on your latest update.**
See the html section I have added a class "img-holder" on div which hold the img and add a class "div_center" on div which contain text's.

img **inherit width** from its **parent div** class "img-holder". "img-holder" and "div_center" **inherit width** from parent div class slider.

N.B: if  you set the img width auto text will always center of the div class slider.

```css
.content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.column {
  float: right;
  width: 225px;
}

.slider {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
}

.img-holder {
  width: inherit;
  
}

.img-holder img {
  width: inherit;/*width auto default value. The browser calculates the width*/
 
}

.div_center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
 <div class="content">  
    <div class="column">
      <div class="slider single-slide">
        <div class="img-holder">
          <img src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2c/d0/19/2cd0197c5eb8c1f84e81734f97e80cd3.jpg' />
         </div><!--./ img-holder -->
        <div class="div_center">
           to place the center of the image
        </div><!--end of txt_center --> 
       
      </div><!--./ slider single-slide-->
    </div><!--./ column -->
  </div><!--./ content -->
```

**Previous:** Position absolute for slick-dots class but you dont set any relative position for that. so you need to add position relative to your slide div. 
And make the image responsive. I have added responsive property for your image on css section and added border on li for clear view.

```css
.content {display: inline-block;}

.column {float:right; width:225px;}

.slider {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
}

.single-slide img {
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.slick-dotted.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
      
    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    border:2px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;
    color: black;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
    <div class="column">
      <div class="slider single-slide">
        <div><img src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2c/d0/19/2cd0197c5eb8c1f84e81734f97e80cd3.jpg' /></div>
        <ul class="slick-dots">
          <li class="active"><button></button></li>
          <li><button></button></li>
          <li><button></button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: how to make dots inherit the width of the image?

Comment: @dmitriy The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element. and image can't be a parent element. body is the main parent element.  in your code div class="slider single-slide is parent of ul section ul is parent of li and li is parent of button means dots .